Why is the area covered by 1 steradian (in a sphere) circular in shape?

why is the shape of area $A$ covered by 1 steradian circular? how do we imagine multiple circles of those dimensions filling up the surface of the sphere?

Just like an area of 1 square cm doesn't have to be a square

The length of 1 cm neednt be in a straight line. It could for example two pieces of half cm

The area doesn't have to be circular.  Any patch of the sphere with an area of $r^2$, no matter its shape, will subtend one steradian of solid angle.
EDIT:  from the comments, you seem to be thinking of an analogy with the arc on a circle that subtends one radian of (plane) angle.  But this is misleading, because the circle is one-dimensional, and so all such arcs are congruent.
To see the parallels:  there is only one "kind" of line segment along a line that has a length of 1 m;  all such line segments are congruent.  But there are many different shapes in a plane that have an area of 1 m2.  Similarly, while all of the (connected) arcs on a circle that subtend 1 radian are congruent, there are many possible shapes on the sphere that subtend 1 steradian.

what i meant was ,like in a circle 1 unit of angle subtends an unique arc length ,what shape would 1 steradian project on a sphere?

@zeus__101 no specific shape, as the answer specifies, only the area of the shape matters

@zeus__101:  Damian is correct.  I've expanded my answer to explain why, with a parallel to 1D & 2D plane geometry.

Steradians are used to measure solid-angle.  It doesn't matter the shape, only the area of the sphere that is covered.  However, it is much easier to show the size of 1 steradian using the simple geometry that arises from using a cone.  It's merely a tool for presentation.  We use steradians specifically in situations where the shape doesn't matter, and we want a unit which allows us to not be concerned with the shape.
You are absolutely free to create a 1 steradian area the shape of a square, or a triangle, or an asterix, or any freeform shape you please.  As long as it has the same area, it will still be a shape subtending 1 steradian.  And you will find that, for the cases scientists choose to use steradians, that choice of a square or triangle won't affect the results at all.  If it did have an effect on the outcome, scientists would not have chosen to use steradians because it wouldn't have been a convenient unit in the first place.
